# Net.HttpWebRequest has no certificates in PowerShell7

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

This code works on PS5, but not on PS7.
It does not throw any error, it simply does not show the certificates

```
$url = "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/azure-app-service/samples/aspnethelloworld/manifests/latest"
$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.GetResponse() | Out-Null
$req.ServicePoint.Certificate | Format-List
```

PS5 Output:

```
> $req.ServicePoint


BindIPEndPointDelegate :
ConnectionLeaseTimeout : -1
Address                : https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/azure-app-service/samples/aspnethelloworld/manifests/latest
MaxIdleTime            : 100000
UseNagleAlgorithm      : True
ReceiveBufferSize      : -1
Expect100Continue      : True
IdleSince              : 1/7/2022 10:30:21 AM
ProtocolVersion        : 1.1
ConnectionName         : https
ConnectionLimit        : 2
CurrentConnections     : 2
Certificate            : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
ClientCertificate      :
SupportsPipelining     : True

> $req.ServicePoint.Certificate | Format-List


Handle  : 2520270205792
Issuer  : CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 05, O=Microsoft Corporation, C=US
Subject : CN=mcr.microsoft.com, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=WA, C=US
```

PS7 Output:

```
> $req.ServicePoint

BindIPEndPointDelegate :
ConnectionLeaseTimeout : -1
Address                : https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/azure-app-service/samples/aspnethelloworld/manifests/latest
MaxIdleTime            : 100000
UseNagleAlgorithm      : True
ReceiveBufferSize      : -1
Expect100Continue      : True
IdleSince              : 07/01/2022 10:27:17
ProtocolVersion        : 1.1
ConnectionName         : https
ConnectionLimit        : 2
CurrentConnections     : 0
Certificate            :
ClientCertificate      :
SupportsPipelining     : True
```

Why is PowerShell 7 not returning Certificates in `[Net.HttpWebRequest]`. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: AFAIK `HttpWebRequest` and related API surface has (deliberately) not been fully ported to .NET 5.0, as it's likely going to be deprecated in a future release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HttpWebRequest` API surface has not been fully ported to the newer versions of .NET/Core, as detailed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29301):

> `HttpWebRequest` is API which is obsolete - see https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md.
> We ported only the most important parts of it to .NET Core.
> **The recommended Networking API is `HttpClient`**.

To inspect the remote certificate using `HttpClient`, you need to leverage a certificate validation callback - in PowerShell 7 that would look something like this:

```
$url = "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/azure-app-service/samples/aspnethelloworld/manifests/latest"

# Create a (thread-safe) hashtable to hold any certificates discovered
$certTable = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})

# Create a handler
$handler = [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler]::new()

# Attach a custom validation callback that saves the remote certificate to the hashtable
$handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = {
  param(
    [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]$Msg,
    [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$Cert,
    [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain]$Chain,
    [System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors]$SslErrors
  )

  # Save the certificate
  $certTable[$Msg.RequestUri] = $Cert

  # Leave actual policy validation as-is
  return [System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors]::None -eq $SslErrors
}.GetNewClosure()

# Create a new http client with our custom handler attached
$client = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new($handler)

# Prepare request message
$request = [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]::new([System.Net.Http.HttpMethod]::Get, $url)

# Send request
$response = $client.Send($request)

# callback routine will now have populated the table with the certificate
$certTable[$request.RequestUri]
```